# Delete rows and row values if string is present

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data sample like this after all pivoting and transformations

| CIRCLE | RecordDate | tenant | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with RCA | 55 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with RCA (%) | 55 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with CIC Issues | 99 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with CIC Issues (%) | 99 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with UIC Issues | 99 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Cells with UIC Issues (%) | 99 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | No PM data found | 0 |
| ATM_AL_WCDMA | 2022-12-08 | atmdza#wcdma | Null counters | 0 |

I am trying to check if string `wcdma` exists in column tenant and if it exists delete the rows - `Cells with RCA (%)` and its value in the `value` column. It should only delete `Cells with RCA (%)` in the `name` column and its corresponding value in the `value` column, tenant name should remain.

It can be achieved by separating into multiple lines, but I don't know if it achieves in a single continuous line.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: playing around something like this ... but its not complete yet --

test.new1 <- grep("wcdma", test$tenant)
subset(test.new1, name != "Cells with RCA (%)")

Comment: In the data you post, `wcdma` exists in all rows - should they all be deleted then?

Comment: So is the logic: "if tenant contains "wcdma" and name == "Cells with RCA (%)" then delete row?"   that could be `library(dplyr);library(stringr); df %>% filter(tenant %>% str_detect("wcdma", negate = TRUE) | name != "Cells with RCA (%)")`. That will keep rows that are either not containing wcdma in tenant, or if they are, only if they don't match "Cells with RCA (%)" in name. ie the only rows getting removed are where both columns DO match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, this is what you are going to need to do:

```r
# Your Data
df <- read.csv(text = "
CIRCLE,RecordDate,tenant,name,value,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with RCA,55,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with RCA (%),55,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with CIC Issues,99,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with CIC Issues (%),99,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with UIC Issues,99,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Cells with UIC Issues (%),99,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,No PM data found,0,
ATM_AL_WCDMA,2022-12-08,atmdza#wcdma,Null counters,0",
                 header= TRUE,
                 sep=",")

# Base R Solution
df <- subset(df,select=-X)

df[grepl('wcdma',df$tenant) &grepl("Cells with RCA \\(%\\)",df$name),][c("name","value")]<-c(NA,NA)

    CIRCLE RecordDate       tenant                      name value
1 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma            Cells with RCA    55
2 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma                      <NA>    NA
3 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma     Cells with CIC Issues    99
4 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma Cells with CIC Issues (%)    99
5 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma     Cells with UIC Issues    99
6 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma Cells with UIC Issues (%)    99
7 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma          No PM data found     0
8 ATM_AL_WCDMA 2022-12-08 atmdza#wcdma             Null counters     0
```